# Loading PCD files using NPM and Three.js

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

I am new with Three.js and I'm struggling to import a PCD file into the scene and I would need some help if possible.

I'm using node.module and I've installed "pcd-format" using npm.

Here is an image of my workspace:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk0sU.png)

I would like to go with as simple code as possible for the beginning, without using some complex packages in order to understand the principles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll answer to my question since I got help on similar issue on the other platform. Here's what I've done:

1. In the Terminal in Visual Studio Code: `npm create vite` , installed "Vanilla" framework, initialized a new project "my-project".
2. After creating "my-project" folder I got files such as main.js , package.json , etc.
3. From "my-project" in Terminal I installed three: `npm install three` and `npm run dev` to serve my app on localhost:3000
4. Then I imported PCDLoader and the script for loading a PCD model that I copied from three.js/docs (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=load#examples/en/loaders/PCDLoader):

```js
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <h1>Ciao</h1>
  <a href="https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html" target="_blank">Documentation</a>
`
import { PCDLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/PCDLoader'
console.log(PCDLoader)

const loader = new PCDLoader();

loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'pointcloud.pcd',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( mesh ) {

        scene.add( mesh );

    },
    // called when loading is in progresses
    function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

    }
);
```

It now works except that the app crashes when I debug and it says that DevTools was disconnected from the page....